# ODBC Informix server: Error while Extracting Month name from the date

Tags: oracle, odbc, informix, data-conversion, yearmonth

I am trying to get the Month name from the date so that I can use the month in the Tableau. Using the MONTH function, I am getting the Month number 1-12 which is coming as Measure Columns in the Tableau.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbTQ9.png)

that's not how I want it.

Then I tried this;

`to_char(to_date(date_required, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') As Base_Month`

It gives me this error;

[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]It is not possible to convert between the specified types.
[Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Invalid cursor received by sqlexec.

I have tried almost every solution but no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Informix Version 14.10.FC10DE, we can do:

```
CREATE TABLE my_dates
(
    date_required DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_dates VALUES ( '2023-08-20' );
INSERT INTO my_dates VALUES ( '2023-01-10' );
```

Then we can use the function "TO_CHAR" to get the month name:

```
SELECT date_required, TO_CHAR( date_required, '%B') AS base_month FROM my_dates;

date_required  2023-08-20
base_month     August

date_required  2023-01-10
base_month     January
```

From the online [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=functions-char-function):

```
Symbol  Meaning
%B      Full month name, as defined in the locale
```

Comment: this worked even in Informix Version 9.59. Thank You so much :)